# Is there a way to update existing variables when merging in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures, merge

I have two datasets I want to merge on the variable `id`, one of which has two possible ids, for example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'q', 'z'),
                  id2 = c('NA', 'g', 'NA', 'd', 'e'),
                  var1 = 1:5,
                  var3 = c('hi', 'hello', 'bonjour', 'howdy', 'hi'))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                  var2 = 6:10,
                  var4 = 20:24)
```

I currently merge these datasets on the primary linking variable:

```
merge1 <- merge(x = df1,
                y = df2,
                by = 'id',
                all = TRUE)
```

I need to re-merge those rows from the first dataframe that have the second id but did not match in the initial merge, so to do that I put them in a separate data frame, take them out of the fully matched dataset, and then merge the two:

```
df1.remerge <- merge1[which(!is.na(merge1$id2) &
                              is.na(merge1$var2)),] 
df1.remerge$id <- df1.remerge$id2

merged <- merge1[which(is.na(merge1$id2) |
                       !is.na(merge1$var2)),]

merge2 <- merge(x = df1.remerge,
                y = merged,
                by = 'id',
                all = TRUE,
                suffixes = c('.m1', '.m2'))
# where .m1 = the remerged obs from df1 & .m2 = the original merged obs
```

This, though, creates two sets of the same variables (i.e. I end up with two `var1`s and two `var2`s). I can of course manually combine the variables, but I'd prefer not to, since my actual data is quite large (think millions of observations and 30-40 variables) and that seems rather inefficient.

Ultimately I want a dataset that looks roughly like this:

```
want.final <- data.frame(id = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                         var1 = 1:5,
                         var2 = 6:10,
                         var3 = c('hi', 'hello', 'bonjour', 'howdy', 'hi'),
                         var4 = 20:24)
```

But what I get with this method is this:

```
get.final <- data.frame(id = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                        var1.m1 = c('NA', 'NA', 'NA', 4, 5),
                        var1.m2 = c(1, 2, 3, 'NA', 'NA'),
                        var2.m1 = c('NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA'),
                        var2.m2 = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
                        var3.m1 = c('NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'howdy', 'hi'),
                        var3.m2 = c('hi', 'hello', 'bonjour', 'NA', 'NA'),
                        var4.m1 = c('NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA'),
                        var4.m2 = c(20, 21, 22, 23, 24))
```

Does anyone know of a way to re-merge these observations and update the existing variables where they're missing in the master/x dataset and not missing in the using/y? In an ideal world I'd like something like the `update` option for Stata's `merge` that does just this.

Comment: What is the expected output? If you can build it with `data.frame(..)` as you did `df1` and `df2`, that would be ideal. Thanks!

Comment: Just updated -- let me know if that's still unclear.

Comment: Even with millions of rows, it is always just two variables, or do you need a programmatic method that repeats this process with more than two `id*` variables?

Comment: It's just the two `id` variables, thankfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to find matching rows between `df1$id` and `df2$id`. For those rows in `df1` where no matches are found, a second attempt should find matching rows between the alternative *id* `df1$id2` and `df2$id`. Furthermore, the datasets are quite large (containing millions of rows) and the OP is restricted more or less to base R.

### Base R

So, instead of doing multiple merges with datasets of millions of rows, we can *resolve the duplicate id columns* in `df1` first before doing a single merge:

```
id1 <- df2$id[match(df1$id,  df2$id)]
id2 <- df2$id[match(df1$id2, df2$id)]
df1$id <- ifelse(is.na(id1), id2, id1)
df1$id2 <- NULL
merge(df1, df2)
```

> ```
>   id var1    var3 var2 var4
> 1  a    1      hi    6   20
> 2  b    2   hello    7   21
> 3  c    3 bonjour    8   22
> 4  d    4   howdy    9   23
> 5  e    5      hi   10   24
> ```

#### Explanation

- First, we check if `df1$id` is included in `df2$id` which returns `id1` as

  ```
  [1] "a" "b" "c" NA  NA
  ```
- Then, we check if `df1$id2` is included in `df2$id` which returns `id2` as

  ```
  [1] NA  NA  NA  "d" "e"
  ```
- Now, we can *coalesce* `id1` and `id2`, i.e., we pick pair-wise the first non-NA value and replace the `id` column in `df1` which becomes

  ```
  [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
  ```
- The `id2` column in `df1` is removed as it is no longer needed.
- Finally, the modified `df1` and `df2` are merged on the `id` column.

### Edit: `data.table` approach

As the OP has pointed out that his production dataset consists of *millions of observations and 30-40 variables* it might be worthwhile to consider a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach. [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) has the `:=` assignment operator which allows for fast update of columns *by reference*.

Using `data.table`, the approach above can be implemented by

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df2[df1[, `:=`(id = fcoalesce(df2[df1, on = "id", x.id], df2[df1, on = "id==id2", x.id]),
          id2 = NULL)], on = "id"]
```

Answer (score 1):

*In general*, `merge` and `dplyr::*_join` will always give you the `*.x`/`*.y` variants of a shared-column; `data.table` is often the same, but its merge-assignment operation can help side-step it.

### base R

```r
out <- merge(merge(df1, df2, by="id", all.x=TRUE), df2,
             by.x="id2", by.y="id", all.x = TRUE, suffixes = c("", ".y"))
out$id[is.na(out$var2)] <- out$id2[is.na(out$var2)]
out$var2[is.na(out$var2)] <- out$var2.y[is.na(out$var2)]
out[,c("id2","var2.y")] <- NULL
out
#   id var1 var2
# 1  d    4    9
# 2  e    5   10
# 3  b    2    7
# 4  a    1    6
# 5  c    3    8
```

### data.table

Renaming `df2$var2` can be useful here for clarity and conditional reassignment.

```r
library(data.table)
DT1 <- as.data.table(df1)
DT2 <- as.data.table(df2)
setnames(DT2, "var2", "var2new")
DT1[DT2, var2 := var2new, on = .(id)
  ][DT2, c("id", "var2") := .(id2, fifelse(is.na(var2), var2new, var2)), on = .(id2 == id)
  ][, id2 := NULL]
#        id  var1  var2
#    <char> <int> <int>
# 1:      a     1     6
# 2:      b     2     7
# 3:      c     3     8
# 4:      d     4     9
# 5:      e     5    10
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I haven't been as clear as I should have been -- I'll have many variables this will apply to (more than just the two I show here, more like 40 or so), so the base R option is maybe not ideal, hence this question. And unfortunately I don't have access to the `data.table` package (I'm working with restricted access data, which means I can only use preapproved packages). If you have more ideas I'd really appreciate it, but thank you all the same.

Comment: I understand (and just realized I omitted a rather import line from the base R block). You're looking for a programmatic way to do this, is that right? If possible, it would help immensely to fill out the sample data a little to reflect at least 1-2 more columns that need to be tested. Is it always just a double-merge step, or is it iteratively merge various `df2`-like frames until all fields are non-`NA`?

Comment: It's just the double-merge, just with more variables. Also I misspoke on `data.table`; I must have misspelled it when I checked for it earlier because we can use that package.